# Characterization of sum of powers of $\omega$.

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

Let $\rho$ be an ordinal different from $0$.

Show that the two classes of ordinals are equivalent:

1. Ordinals $\alpha < \omega^{\rho}$ such that $\alpha = \omega^{\xi_0} + \ldots +\omega^{\xi_{p-1}}$ where $\rho > \xi_0 > \ldots > \xi_{p-1}$.
2. Ordinal $\alpha < \omega^{\rho}$ such that $\alpha = 0$ or there do not exist $\beta,\gamma,\delta < \omega^{\rho}$ such that $\alpha = \beta + \gamma + \gamma + \delta$ and $\gamma+\delta \neq \delta$.

I'm not very familiar with ordinal arithmetic. What kind of information could I use to prove this characterization?

Comment: Not to be a troll, but without familiarity with ordinal arithmetic, how could one possibly prove statements about ordinal arithmetic? I feel like the obvious answer to your question is "foundational defintions and facts about ordinal arithmetic, and the experience of having worked through some first simpler examples".

Comment: @GregMartin this is a statement from a research paper "The first-order properties of products of algebraic systems", section 10. I just need some idea to get the right direction and understand the result I'm interested in.

Comment: Look up the Cantor normal form theorem.